# how to query maas API with curl

Tags: command-line, maas, curl

I am trying to figure out how to query the MAAS server using curl.

I am starting to experiment with CLI query so that I may build a python script for remote command and query without having to use the MAAS CLI app.

The end goal is to control/query MAAS with ansible.

I tried:

```
curl -u "username:password"  "http://machine/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/?op=list"
```

The response was:

```
Unrecognised signature: GET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that MAAS requires authentication before it will return the node listing. MAAS normally authenticates API requests through OAuth, not [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which is what `curl -u` uses by default for web URLs.

Luckily, MAAS also provides a Python client library called `apiclient` which is included in the `python-maas-client` package. Using that library would allow you to trivially issue the query with an apikey, which you can get from http://$MAAS_URL/MAAS/account/prefs/. Assuming you have APIKEY and MAAS_URL, the below snippet demonstrates how you'd fetch the listing:

```
APIKEY = "foo:bar:baz"
MAAS_URL = "http://my.maas.host/MAAS/api/1.0"

from apiclient import maas_client
auth = maas_client.MAASOAuth(*APIKEY.split(":"))
client = maas_client.MAASClient(auth, maas_client.MAASDispatcher(), MAAS_URL)
print client.get(u"nodes/", "list").read()
```

Incidentally, AIUI `curl -X GET` is the query type `curl` issues by default.

[*] I believe marking the path as unicode should not be necessary, but there's an assertion in the code that may be a bug. Reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1418158.

Comment: See http://blog.allenap.me/2013/06/workaround-for-uploading-files-to-maas.html for a more complete example of using the maas_client module.

Comment: I got this to work beautifully, thanks.  http://dpaste.com/0ETVXZ1

Comment: Cool, but you don't need the first import statement, as you're using everything inside maas_client!

Comment: Note to self: check to see whether using https://github.com/mojodna/oauth-proxy would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Example of post in the maas-api

```
desiredSettings = {
    "ip_range_high": "10.30.0.252",
    "ip_range_low": "10.30.0.152",
    "broadcast_ip": "10.30.0.255",
    "name": "eth3",
    "ip": "10.30.0.0",
    "subnet_mask": "255.255.255.0",
    "management": "2",
    "interface": "eth3"
}

#resp = client.post(u"nodegroups/%s/interfaces/" % (cluster_uuid), "new", **desiredSettings)
```

Answer (score -1):

I looked at http://marsweather.ingenology.com/ and found this example

```
curl -X GET http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/
```

plus other shell code using "curl". I think that will get you started. You still need to have tools to deal with JSON, but that seems out of scope for this question.

Comment: Failed with: curl -X GET -A "Mozilla/4.0" "http://10.34.20.34/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/?op=list"

Comment: Okay, but note that the Mars Atmospheric Aggregation System API is not the MAAS the OP was referring to!