# POST request using python-maas-client

Tags: python, maas, curl

We can use python-maas-client for accessing the maas API.

I need to know the way of performing the post request towards maas using the python-maas-client.

**Here it is important links:**

*Link for MAAS API documentation:*

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/api.html

*Making GET request sample:*

[how to query maas API with curl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581444/how-to-query-maas-api-with-curl)

Some one please provide me with a sample post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sshKeys = {"key": [keyValue]}
maas_access.post(u"account/prefs/sshkeys/", "new", **sshKeys)
```

The above code will post the ssh key into the maas using maas-api.